# EJS: Pass array of pages into include(page)

Tags: node.js, ejs

I've created a dashboard page where a user can save different components of the site to one page for quick viewing. I'm able to dynamically load one component as follows:

index.js

```
res.render('dashboard',{comp: 'component1'});
```

dashboard.ejs

```
<%- include(comp) %>
```

but I would like to do something like this:

index.js

```
res.render('dashboard',{comp: ['component1', 'component3']});
```

And have the ejs page loop through the include(), this way i can show 0 to n components on the dashboard page.

I've tried wrapping the include in a for loop like so:

```
<%- for(c in comp){include(c)} %>
```

but ejs did not like this.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <% for(var i=0; i < comp.length; ++i) { %>
    <%- include(comp[i]) %>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. I didn't think about multiple <% %> tags

Answer (score 1):

> in your code, c is the index not value, comp[c] is your component.

```
<% for(c in comp){ %>
       <%- include(comp[c]) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, stupid mistake on my end. I think what was causing me my real issue was I was trying to do it within one set of <% %> tags.